# Can a php application instantiate multiple RNGs

Tags: php

Update - this question applies to PHP < `8.2` - for 8.2+, You have access to [Randomizer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.random-randomizer.php)

---

PHP supports `mt_rand()` and `mt_srand()`, but these are global and static.

I notice in the PHP [C source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/random/random.c#L436) that `mt_rand` uses a `engine_mt19937` instance; is there a way in PHP to instantiate our own instance of this RNG so we can control its seed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On PHP 8.2+, yes. See [@AlexHowansky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74995816/1941241) for that. On earlier PHP versions, no.

Your link to the source code points to the `master` branch, which already has the PHP 8.2 logic in it since it was officially released last month. That is why the `master` branch includes the reference to an MT19937 engine.

On older versions (e.g. the latest [8.1 branch](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-8.1/ext/standard/mt_rand.c#L157)) you can see that `mt_rand()` did not use a configurable engine but just checked if it was already seeded. PHP 8.1 and earlier used a single global generator for `mt_rand()` so it is not possible to have multiple RNGs with different seeds if you want to use the native functions.

Having said that, you could probably roll your own implementation of an MT19937 RNG for PHP 8.1. [Others have](https://gist.github.com/Kcazer/c8f6d53951b77ca5e12b79585979a05c).

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way in PHP to instantiate our own instance of this RNG so we can control its seed?

With PHP 8.2+, yes. See the [\Random](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.random.php) classes. You can do something like:

```
$rand1 = new \Random\Engine\Mt19937($seed1);
$value1 = $rand1->generate();

$rand2 = new \Random\Engine\Mt19937($seed2);
$value2 = $rand2->generate();
```

Comment: Thanks - sorry, but my question wasn't clear - we don't have 8.2 yet, so these engines and `Randomizer` are still teasing us